# Get a window text by handle

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, hook, spy++

I use UI Spy and Spy++ to view windows text of some windows, but none offers a result. As people said, some windows are built up and executed by some components, say they are embedded inside those components. Except the two tools to view the window handles, text, could you introduce me other tools or ways to get a window text or handle without using hooks ?

Edit: I also use Spy Object to retrieve windows objects information and search from ancestors till I can meet the right object but this tool to the particular windows I am watching is incapable to do the job because it also reports incorrect parents positions in ancestor hierarchy, I try out the MAAS and UI-Automation without luck, Thank you for you help.

Edit3: I don't like their windows'ideas of internal designs (I mean only they-designers- know how to untie the knots)

Comment: Those are the two tools. Not all windows *have* text (captions), at least not text that is retrievable with the [`WM_GETTEXT` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627.aspx). What kinds of windows are you looking at?

Comment: Thank you, I also try to send that message with the correct (sure) intptr of the embeded windows'handle but the return string is empty. However the Spy Object offers the correct string.

Comment: Can you tell what the UI framework the app is written with?  (Java, WPF, etc)

Comment: I don't know what Spy Object is, but as I said, not all windows will return a response to the `WM_GETTEXT` message. If your window isn't returning a response, then it's not going to display the string in Spy++ either, as far as I know. Do note that if these are WPF controls you're examining, they're not standard Win32 controls and thus they're not guaranteed to meet all the same specifications as the standard Win32 controls.

Comment: Thank you, agent and Cody, I edit my OP to clearify.

Comment: @UieiSio - The closest way to scrape text from controls is to use some sort of OCR from a screenshot and I don't know of any tools that use it because by itself it can't be guaranteed. If what your doing in your situation doesn't work then it is likely nothing will.

Comment: Thank you, the snapshots taking implemented as a hidden function to catch users who-who is dangerous [Steve Jobs was a bad guy!].

Answer (score 0):

Usually the Accessibility APIs are used, the ones used for text-to-speech screen readers for blind users.  In your question you mentioned MAAS, did you mean MSAA (Microsoft Active Accessibility)?  If not, that's where I'd look next.

Answer (score 0):

http://white.codeplex.com/ is a great framework which does such things.

> White is a framework for automating rich client applications based on Win32, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and SWT (Java) platforms. It is .NET based and does not require the use of any proprietary scripting languages. Tests/automation programs using White can be written with whatever .NET language, IDE and tools you are already using. White provides a consistent object-oriented API, hiding the complexity of Microsoft's UIAutomation library (on which White is based) and windows messages. Only stable versions of White are released, so all releases are production-ready.